# JQuery: Validation on Disabled Option in Select Field

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to do detection on a select field. By default the first item selected is disabled and acts as a prompt for the user "Select option".

I want to check if this "disabled" item is still selected when the form is submitted and if it is then ask the user to select one of the options in the field. Currently for some reason the validation error throws up when any option is selected. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<select name="purchasableId" id="metreSelect" class="metre" required>
  <option disabled selected>Select option</option>
  <option value="Dynamic Options">Dynamic Options</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#add').click(function(){

  if ($(".metre").children('option').attr('disabled')) {
     $('.metreValidation').html("<span class='flash'>Please select the number of metres</span>");
     $('.metre').addClass("errorBorder");
     var errorMessage = 'true';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query `$(".metre").children('option').attr('disabled')` just checks if there is *any* disabled option, which always is true. You rather should check if the *selected* option is disabled:

```
if ($('.metre').find('option:selected').attr('disabled')) {
  // show the error
}
```